# How to get all assets from a folder under /content/dam/folder in aem

Tags: assets, dam

I'm working on dam assets - I want to get all assets under/content/dam/folder?
please let me know if anyone has idea on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@sam- This is basic query which returns all the assets,

```
path=/content/dam/<root-folder>
type=dam:Asset
p.limit=-1
```

please check this out.

Answer (score 0):

use query builder api to build a query that will fetch all the assets.